# Spark Turtorial 1.2 for python

Tags: apache-spark

I'm new to spark,I've just stacked in this apache spark tutorial

Self-Contained Applications

http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/quick-start.html

```
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.2.0
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.9 (default, Dec 15 2014 10:37:34)
SparkContext available as sc.
>>> from pyspark import SparkContext
>>> logFile = "local/share/spark//README.md"  # Should be some file on your system
>>> sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/share/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 102, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway)
  File "/usr/local/share/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 228, in _ensure_initialized
    callsite.function, callsite.file, callsite.linenum))
ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=PySparkShell, master=local[*]) created by <module> at /usr/local/share/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py:45
```

mac 10.10.2

python 2.7.9

spark release:1.2

spark package:hadoop2.4 or later

thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3):

When you run a Spark shell you don't need to create your own `SparkContext` - it's already provided as the `sc` object.

Comment: Hence the *"SparkContext available as sc."* line when you start the shell.

Answer (score 0):

not just `sc`  we can not even create any other object using SparkContext like 
`sc_1 = SparkContext()`
It will again throw the error `ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=PySparkShell, master=local[*])`